# How to declare variable in Mathematica and use them later

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I am very new to Mathematica and I was curious about how one can declare variable and use them later in function. I tried to do as below but I'm getting empty result in Graph

Here I've declared two variable one and two and tried to use them later but it didn't output the result.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that `x^2` or `Superscript[x,2]` ?  Do `one /. x->0 ` what do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
one:=3*x^2/2;
two:=x;
Show[Plot[one/two,{x,0,15}],ListPlot[{1,3,7,9,10,11,14}]]
```

Comment: it works perfectly...one question why the fraction doesn't work but instead '/' ...it works.

Comment: It isn't the formatting of the fraction that made this work. Compare mine and yours character-by-character until you find the other difference between yours and mine. That is what made it work.